# Changing storyboard segue `kind` between "Show" and "ShowDetail": why does the change not take effect when running the simulator?

Tags: swift, ios9, xcode7

First of all, note that this is not a question about *"how to finish my app?"* or *"why is my app not working?"*, but covers an issue that I happened to stumble upon while playing around with a simple app, and that I cannot for the world of me explain. Perhaps someone here at SO can explain why this apparent issue happens.

---

For the sake of learning, I've been playing around with a simple app consisting of an `UITableViewController` embedded in an `Navigation Controller`. From the table view cells (subclass of `UITableViewCell`) one can navigate to a simple `UIViewController`. See the storyboard overview of the app below, and note that this shows the state of the app (development) just prior to setting the segue transition between the table view cells to the view controller.

[image: App overview, Storyboard]

Now, in my app, I tested two different type of segues between the table view cells and the view controller, namely

1. A "Show" segue from the cells to the view controller, [as can be seen in this gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j3eJO.gif).
2. A "ShowDetail" segue from the cells to the view controller, [as can be seen in this gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fw8EL.gif).

Based on the on the [Apple documentation on storyboard segues](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_storyboard/Chapters/StoryboardSegue.html), I expect, while running the app, the following behavior in the view controller part of my app:

- With the "Show" segue, the view controller scene will be presented with a navigation controller bar, containing a default "Back" button on the top left corner of the scene (within the bar). Let's denote this as behaviour (A) from here on, and [see this image for visualisation of it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ViQ88.png).
- With the "ShowDetail" segue, no navigation bar will be present. We'll denote this as behaviour (B) from here on, and [see this image for visualisation of it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vX1UE.png).

Both cases 1. and 2. above yield their expected results, behaviour (A) and (B), respectively.

Now to the part that I cannot explain:

3. I set my segue to "Show", and thereafter change---in the attributes inspector---the segue into kind "ShowDetail", [as can be seen in this gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0LS78.gif). After the change, everything looks good in the storyboard (no navigation controller bar in the view controller), but when running the app, I still get behaviour (A), i.e., the behaviour expected for the "Show" segue.
4. If I do the vice versa; create a "ShowDetail" segue and change into "Show" via the attributes inspector ([as can be seen in this gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vQmZK.gif)), I get the same unexpected (for me) behaviour, namely behaviour (B), i.e., the behaviour expected for the "ShowDetail" segue (no navigation controller bar)

I can also track the same unexpected behaviour by logging the the following boolean:

```
// In the ViewController code (ViewController.swift)
let presentingViewIsNavigationController = 
    presentingViewController is UINavigationController
```

- Situation 1. above (using "Show" segue and not changing it) yields, as expected, `false` (presenting view here is the `UITableViewController`, and both this and the `UIViewController` is wrapped in the navigation controller).
- Situation 2. above yields, as expected, `true` (navigation controller is the presenting view of the `UIViewController`).
- Situation 3. above yields, unexpectedly, `false`.
- Situation 4. above yields, unexpectedly, `true`.

---

**Question:** Why does the change of segue kind "Show" to/from "ShowDetail"---performed in the attributes inspector---seemingly not take effect when running app in the simulator?

I'm running Xcode 7.2, and iOS 9.2 in the simulator (simulating an iPhone 6s plus).

Comment: Sometimes I change something in the storyboard here or there, and the updates are not effective immediately. I usually change it to something else and try to run, then return it to the value I want and run again, and it might work. Other times I try to clean project.

Comment: @hannad I see. I'm interested in the "why" such updates are not effective immediately. In my case, I have tried to clean the project but still get the same unexpected (non-updated) behaviour. Perhaps, in the specific example above, I need to change something more, in addition to the segue kind in the attributes inspector. If so, I would really like to know what that additional change is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One problem with segues that I found while testing is that the action attribute doesn't change when you change the segue kind:

```
<segue destination="YYV-02-abX" kind="show" identifier="segueshow" id="X7i-33-rvh"/>
<segue destination="YYV-02-abX" kind="showDetail" identifier="segueshowdetails" id="crf-TU-94x"/>
<segue destination="YYV-02-abX" kind="showDetail" identifier="segueshowtoshowdetails" action="showViewController:sender:" id="w2L-45-p7H"/>
<segue destination="YYV-02-abX" kind="show" identifier="segueshowdetailstoshow" action="showDetailViewController:sender:" id="7Z4-mJ-Pbh"/>
```

So this might be a bug on the Apple side.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Have you tried to performed the segue kind change and following that, manually updating the action in the code? Also, how can I access the <segue ...> code nibs you show above? (So I can try it for myself to verify that this is, in fact, the source of this "bug")

Comment: No, I haven't done any further research, you can read and edit any xib or storyboard files as xml documents using preferred tools. E.g. removing the new action tag (which for some matches the original segue kind) should make the modified segue practically the same as if it was created with the new kind You might also be able play around and use your own actions set there, although almost certainly something will eventually break if you do so.

Comment: Thanks for quick response, I see, I'll look into it today. However, as you note, only for playing around to understand this issue, and not something I'd prefer to do in practice as I will most likely break something sooner or later.